Neon on Raspberry Pi 5 to accelerate RGB2GRay, 128bit (Q register) slower than 64bit(D register), why?
As the title says, I have a Raspberry Pi 5 (Cortex-A76 by Armv8; four cores), and I use OpenCV to do something on it.
I use cv::cvtColor to get RGB2Gray, it is slow on Raspberry Pi 5, so I use neon_arm.h to optimize speed and it's indeed faster.
In Version-1, I use vld3_u8(), which loads a uint8x8x3_t of data from image each times (64 bit register).
In Version-2 I, use vld3q_u8() ,which load a uint8x16x3_t of data from image each times(128 bit).
I use std::chrono to timing the code; strangely, the Version-1 is faster than Version-2 (In my opinion should slower).
Version-1 : 10.5ms ( average for 100times).
Version-2 : 12.7ms (avg for 100times).
The photo size is 3009x4248.
I don't know whether anything wrong (maybe device or code?).
Anyone can teach me why?
I show my code as follow .

void neon_cv_8(cv::Mat &src,cv::Mat &grey,std::size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *p_img = src.data;
    uint8_t *p_o = grey.data;
    uint8x8_t r_corr = vdup_n_u8(76);
    uint8x8_t g_corr = vdup_n_u8(150);
    uint8x8_t b_corr = vdup_n_u8(30);


    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<size ; i+=8)
    {
        uint8x8x3_t vdata = vld3_u8(p_img);
        uint16x8_t tmp = vmull_u8(b_corr, vdata.val[0]);
        tmp = vmlal_u8(tmp, g_corr, vdata.val[1]);
 
        tmp = vmlal_u8(tmp, r_corr, vdata.val[2]);
        uint8x8_t vgray = vshrn_n_u16(tmp, 8);
        
        vst1_u8(p_o, vgray);
        p_o += 8;
        p_img += 8 * 3;
    }
}//version-1

void neon_cv_16(cv::Mat &src,cv::Mat &grey,std::size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *p_img = src.data;
    uint8_t *p_o = grey.data;
    uint16x4_t r_corr = vdup_n_u16(76);
    uint16x4_t g_corr = vdup_n_u16(150);
    uint16x4_t b_corr = vdup_n_u16(30);


    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<size ; i+=2*8)
    {
        
        uint8x16x3_t vdata = vld3q_u8(p_img);
        uint16x8_t v_b = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(vdata.val[0])),
                    v_g = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(vdata.val[1])),
                    v_r = vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(vdata.val[2]));

        uint32x4_t tmp_low = vmull_u16(b_corr, vget_low_u16(v_b));
        uint32x4_t tmp_high = vmull_u16(b_corr,vget_high_u16(v_b));

        tmp_low = vmlal_u16(tmp_low,g_corr, vget_low_u16(v_g));
        tmp_high = vmlal_u16(tmp_high,g_corr,vget_high_u16(v_g));

        tmp_low = vmlal_u16(tmp_low,r_corr, vget_low_u16(v_r));
        tmp_high = vmlal_u16(tmp_high,r_corr,vget_high_u16(v_r));
        uint8x8_t vgray0 = vqmovn_u16(vcombine_u16(vrshrn_n_u32(tmp_low,8)
                        ,vrshrn_n_u32(tmp_high,8)));
        
        v_r = vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(vdata.val[0])),
        v_g = vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(vdata.val[1])),
        v_b = vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(vdata.val[2]));
        
        tmp_low = vmull_u16(b_corr, vget_low_u16(v_b));
        tmp_high = vmull_u16(b_corr,vget_high_u16(v_b));

        tmp_low = vmlal_u16(tmp_low,g_corr, vget_low_u16(v_g));
        tmp_high = vmlal_u16(tmp_high,g_corr,vget_high_u16(v_g));

        tmp_low = vmlal_u16(tmp_low,r_corr, vget_low_u16(v_r));
        tmp_high = vmlal_u16(tmp_high,r_corr,vget_high_u16(v_r));
        uint8x8_t vgray1 = vqmovn_u16(vcombine_u16(vrshrn_n_u32(tmp_low,8)
                        ,vrshrn_n_u32(tmp_high,8)));
        
        vst1q_u8(p_o, vcombine_u8(vgray0,vgray1));
        p_o += 16;
        p_img += 48;
    }
}//version-2


What compiler?  What optimization options?  Does that CPU have anything like Turbo where it clocks higher until it gets too hot, then drops back to a sustainable speed?  Does benchmarking the functions in the opposite order change the results?

My optimization options are: -O3  -mcpu=cortex-a76 -free-vectorize and the version is Gcc-12.2.0  on Debian 12. I have installed the heat sink and fan on the CPU. It does indeed cause frequency reduction due to overheating but not when running code. I will change my benchmark later and try again.

hello, I opened the target file on IDA to look at the assembly, surprisingly the assembly code doesn't contain the neon instruct (just plain asm), but the value of __ARM_NEON macro is true. More generally, if I use the neon intrinsic function, it just generates plain asm code; if I embed the neon asm code then it doesn't generate any code in asm. I don't know what I should do now.

I don't think it's plausible that GCC could compile intrinsics to scalar asm on integer regs.  Many AArch64 SIMD instructions use the same mnemonics as their scalar counterparts, e.g. add, but on vector registers which is how you can tell they're SIMD.  (Unlike ARMv7 / AArch32 where the mnemonics were named like vadd.)  If that doesn't explain what you're seeing, you could show an example of what you're talking about on https://godbolt.org/ (it has AArch64 compilers.)

Everything is as you said. Thanks very much!

Unlike the old 32-bit ARMv7, ARM64 SIMD is 16 bytes wide. Intrinsics like vget_high_something are no longer free; they compile into shuffle instructions. vget_low_something are still free, though.
You should use vmull_high_u16 and vmlal_high_u16 to do the math on the higher halves of your vectors without shuffles. Similarly, vqmovn_high_u16 to reduce result to bytes.
Update One more thing, it seems in your version 2 your math is too wide. You’re upcasting bytes into uint16_t, then multiplying uint16_t into uint32_t, then compressing back into bytes. Try the following function instead, untested:
void neon_cv_v3( const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& grey, size_t size )
{
    const uint8_t* p_img = src.data;
    const uint8_t* const p_imgEnd = p_img + size * 3;
    uint8_t* p_o = grey.data;

    const uint8x16_t r_corr = vdupq_n_u8( 76 );
    const uint8x16_t g_corr = vdupq_n_u8( 150 );
    const uint8x16_t b_corr = vdupq_n_u8( 30 );

    while( p_img < p_imgEnd )
    {
        // Load 48 bytes = 16 BGR pixels, and split into channels
        const uint8x16x3_t vdata = vld3q_u8( p_img );
        p_img += 48;

        // Multiply/accumulate these numbers using widening multiplications
        uint16x8_t low = vmull_u8( vget_low_u8( vdata.val[ 0 ] ), vget_low_u8( b_corr ) );
        uint16x8_t high = vmull_high_u8( vdata.val[ 0 ], b_corr );

        low = vmlal_u8( low, vget_low_u8( vdata.val[ 1 ] ), vget_low_u8( g_corr ) );
        high = vmlal_high_u8( high, vdata.val[ 1 ], g_corr );

        low = vmlal_u8( low, vget_low_u8( vdata.val[ 2 ] ), vget_low_u8( r_corr ) );
        high = vmlal_high_u8( high, vdata.val[ 2 ], r_corr );

        // Shift right by 8 bits using rounding, then truncate from uint16_t into uint8_t
        const uint8x8_t grey8 = vrshrn_n_u16( low, 8 );
        const uint8x16_t grey16 = vrshrn_high_n_u16( grey8, high, 8 );

        // Store 16 bytes of the greyscale output
        vst1q_u8( p_o, grey16 );
        p_o += 16;
    }
} // neon_cv_v3

